# How to plot two data sets into using same bin size?

Tags: matplotlib

I have two different data sets. I want to plot histogram using two different data sets but keeping the bins same, there width and range of each bin should be same.

```
Data1 = np.array([1,2,3,3,5,6,7,8])
Data2 = np.array[1,2,3,4,6,7,8,8]
n,bins,patches = plt.hist(Data1,bins=20)
plt.ylabel("no of states")
plt.xlabel("bins")

plt.savefig("./DOS")`
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the `bins` returned from your first histogram plot as an argument to the second histogram to make sure both have the same bin sizes.

---

**Complete answer:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Data1 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8])
Data2 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 8])
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(Data1, bins=20, label='Data 1')
plt.hist(Data2, bins=bins, label='Data 2')
plt.ylabel("no of states")
plt.xlabel("bins")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the documentation for [matplotlib.pyplot.hist](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html) and you will see that the `bins` argument can be an integer (defining the number of bins) or a sequence (defining the edges of the bins themselves).

Therefore, you need to manually define the bins you want to use and pass these to `plt.hist`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

bin_edges = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
data = np.random.rand(50) * 8 

plt.hist(data, bins=bin_edges)
```